# Modify content of an external <div> with <select>, but without JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an HTML page which looks something like this,

```html
<select id="selectMe">
  <option value="option1">Question 1</option>
  <option value="option2">Question 2</option>
  <option value="option3">Question 3</option>
</select>
<div id="option1">Answer 1</div>
<div id="option2">Answer 2</div>
<div id="option3">Answer 3</div>
```

I want to use the `<select>` element to choose which answer `<div>` to show. Unfortunately, I cannot use any JavaScript and must do this with HTML / CSS only.

Also note I'm not hell-bent on using `<select>` if some other form elements will make this easier. But not using any JavaScript is a hard restriction for me.

Comment: can you have a server? The first thing that comes to my mind is to submit a form and reload the page?

Comment: No server allowed either. But I'm happy to type out all content in the HTML document and cleverly hide/show it

Comment: I can't think of a way to hide something without using JS. But what about using anchors in a href e.g. #option1 and then setting each div styled to be height of the screen.

Comment: from where those answers are coming? do you have all those hard coded in your html?

Comment: yes all are hard-coded in HTML (assume a fixed sized list of 5 elements)

Comment: So there will be always 5 questions only and their corresponding answers all are static?

Comment: Did javascript allow `<select onchange=" /*here is code*/ ">` inside tag?

Comment: no in-line JS allowed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mean there is one-way (not totally proud of it) but using `radio` buttons help us to track `checked` state using the `:checked` pseudo-selector. We can use the same to map from `question1` to `option1` and so on.

```css
.options{
display:none;
}
#question1:checked ~ #option1,
#question2:checked ~ #option2,
#question3:checked ~ #option3{
display:block;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="questions" id="question1" checked/>
<label for="question1">Quesion 1</label>

<input type="radio" name="questions" id="question2"/>
<label for="question2">Question 2</label>

<input type="radio" name="questions" id="question3"/>
<label for="question3">Question 3</label>

<div id="option1" class="options">Answer 1</div>
<div id="option2" class="options">Answer 2</div>
<div id="option3" class="options">Answer 3</div>
```

Comment: Nice. I am wondering why you don't like this solution. It looks great to me. (Well, you could avoid that CSS rule with the `.options` selector altogether and use CSS rules like `#question1:not(:checked) ~ #option1 { display: none; }` instead. That would avoid the explicit `display: block;`. And you could combine the three remaining CSS selectors in a single CSS rule, which would be a little more compact.)

Comment: @BartHofland Hey thanks for the suggestion. I don't like it because I was unable to combine the 3 rules into a single generic which works for all.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of a way to hide elements without JS, however, you could use page anchors.

1. Make the divs match the height of the screen
2. Use anchors to link to the divs on page
3. Fix the nav to the top of the screen so that on scrolling it doesn't disappear
4. Disable the user scrolling which would make it appear to hide/show the divs.

Hope this helps.

```html
<div class="sticky">
  <a href="#option1">Question 1</a>
  <a href="#option2">Question 2</a>
  <a href="#option3">Question 3</a>
</div>

<div id="option1" class="full-height blue">Answer 1</div>
<div id="option2" class="full-height green">Answer 2</div>
<div id="option3" class="full-height red">Answer 3</div>

<style>
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  background: white;
}
.full-height {
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
.blue { background: blue; }
.green { background: green; }
.red { background: red; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the CSS [CheckBox Hack](https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/). You will however need to build your own `<select>` because unfortunately it is not possible to put HTML tags inside an `<option>`.

The basic idea is outlined below. On the linked page you can also find an example for how to hide and show content.

```css
.visually-hidden {
    position: absolute;
    left: -100vw;
}

.dropdown-header::after {
    content: "> Options (Click to expand)";
}

#option1:checked ~ .dropdown-header::after {
    content: "Question 1";
}

#option2:checked ~ .dropdown-header::after {
    content: "Question 2";
}

#option3:checked ~ .dropdown-header::after {
    content: "Question 3";
}

.answer::after {
    content: "";
}

#option1:checked ~ .answer::after {
    content: "Answer 1";
}

#option2:checked ~ .answer::after {
    content: "Answer 2";
}

#option3:checked ~ .answer::after {
    content: "Answer 3";
}

.dropdown:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

#dropdown:checked ~ .dropdown {
  display: inline;
}

.dropdown {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="visually-hidden" id="dropdown">
  <label for="dropdown" class="dropdown-header"></label><br>

  <label class="dropdown" for="option1">Question 1</label><input type="radio" id="option1" name="rad" class="visually-hidden" checked><br>
  <label class="dropdown" for="option2">Question 2</label><input id="option2" type="radio" class="visually-hidden" name="rad"/><br>
  <label class="dropdown" for="option3">Question 3</label><input id="option3" type="radio" class="visually-hidden" name="rad"/><br>
  <div class="answer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like it was mentioned before the best way is to use inputs with types radio or checkbox depending on what you want to achieve. The example of using radio buttons and labels is here https://codepen.io/alekskorovin/pen/abBeqzN

```css
.answer-toggle,
.answer {
  display: none;
}

.answer-toggle:checked ~ .answer,
.question {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label class="question" for="answer1">Question 1</label>
<label class="question" for="answer2">Question 2</label> 
<label class="question" for="answer3">Question 3</label> 

<div>
  <input class="answer-toggle" type="radio" name="answer" id="answer1">
  <div class="answer">Answer 1</div>
</div>
<div>
  <input class="answer-toggle" type="radio" name="answer" id="answer2">
  <div class="answer">Answer 2</div>
</div>
<div>
  <input class="answer-toggle" type="radio" name="answer" id="answer3">
  <div class="answer">Answer 3</div>
</div>
```

if you remove the same name="answer" then each answer could be shown independently.